# Detect not contemplated values in a CASE statement evaluation

Tags: t-sql

Is there a way in T-SQL to collect all not contemplated values in a CASE condition and insert them in a table?

For example:

A SELECT that reads a table that has in Col1 the values A,B,C. This SELECT has a CASE that goes like this: `CASE WHEN Col1 = 1 THEN ... WHEN Col1 = B THEN ... ELSE NULL END AS NewCol1`

I would like to detect values like C, values that are not contemplated in Col1. 
I could get them like this:  `(...) ELSE Tabl1.Col1` but I need the CASE statement to end with `ELSE NULL`.

Comment: I do not understand how you can want the case statement to end with else null but also want other values.  This feels like saying you want 1=0.

Comment: I know. It's not my requeriment, it's from a client who wants to keep track of unexpected input values this way.. I suggested them to query the table with a group by and getting all possible combinations of inputs and its respective 'converted' values. Then.. when the convertion becomes NULL or something else.. you know that that particular combination of inputs is not expected. You sould run this query periodically. But they find this solution too difficult to interpret. Im trying to find it a more redeable format.. but I dont come up with nothing.

Comment: Can you add the original Col1 to the select statement?  Then you can see what the original Col1 value is (was?) when NewCol1 is null.

Comment: Yes that's what I did. But they dont like it. Also, it would mean to create a separate query to check  every CASE statement inputs.. and we have a lot of tables...

Comment: Or, if varchar(), I have done something like this: `case when Col1 = 1 then ... ELSE 'UNEXPECTED VALUE ' + Col1 + ' FOUND FOR COL1! END`

Comment: Thanks, but it's important to keep the ```ELSE NULL```at the end.

Comment: Maybe a debug style flag?  `declare @debug=1` then `case when Col1 = 1 then ... ELSE case when @debug=1 then Col1 else NULL end end`.  You can flip the behavior with the @debug "flag".

Comment: Thanks, that last one is interesting, it's like giving two outputs to the same statement.That would avoid to repeat code.  I could call the procedure/function with the parameter and Insert the debugged values in a separate table... That could work!

Comment: Perhaps it would help to add a calculated `bit` column, e.g. `ExpectedValue`, to indicate whether the value was a "known unknown" or an "unknown unknown". If you put the resulting query into a `view` then you can use it with `... where ExpectedValue = 1` for normal use, e.g. reporting, and with `... where ExpectedValue = 0` to get the _funny_ values. Aside: When creating an administrative site for webish things I've written, the initial page is a dashboard of sorts that reports on all manner of _exceptions_, e.g. incorrectly configured logging triggers, offices with zero employees, ... .

Comment: Please, share a code example of this bit column. I dont understand your idea.

Comment: `select ..., cast( case when Col1 = '$' then 1 ... else 0 end as Bit ) as ExpectedValue from ...;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of these values like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1
FROM Table
WHERE Col1 not in (1,...,B)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes that would do it, but that would mean to replicate the CASE evaluation values from the main query, which can be difficult to mantain when updating it. I know it is a difficult situation to solve... thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As @avery_larry suggested, I used a debug flag, giving my query two behaviours. I could call a function/stored with the parameter and if it's up INSERT the values into a desired output.